# Share Point list conditional formatting output percentage

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-list

A quick question from my side, I have written a code to highlight a cell under specific circumstances.

Could you please modify it to output number as a percentage with two decimal places?

```
{   
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json <https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json> ",   
  "debugMode": true,   
  "elmType": "div",   
  "attributes": 
  {     
    "class": "=if(@currentField >= 0.5, 'sp-field-severity--good', if(@currentField >= 0.25,'sp-field-severity--warning', if(@currentField < 0.25,'sp-field-severity--blocked', ''))"   }, 
    "children": [     
      {       
        "elmType": "span",       
        "style": 
        {         
          "display": "inline-block",         
          "padding": "0 4px"       
        },       
        "attributes": 
        {
          "iconName": "=if(@currentField == 'Scheduled','CheckMark', if(@currentField == 'In Process', 'Forward', if(@currentField == 'Cancelled', 'Error', if(@currentField == 'Rescheduled','Warning','')"       
        }     
      },     
      {       
        "elmType": "span",       
        "txtContent": "@currentField"     
      }   
    ] 
  }
```

Comment: I don't know what this is, but it's not JSON Schema. You may want to add some more relevent tags, or the right person might not find this question

Comment: I uesed it for sharepoint list formatting... can you suggest correct tags?

Comment: How about sharepoint?